# Python equivalent of C struct for writing bytes to a file

Tags: python, file, struct

What could be the simplest Python equivalent to the following C code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct dog {
        char breed[16];
        char name[16];
    };
    struct person {
        char name[16];
        int age;
        struct dog pets[2];
    };
    struct person p = {
        "John Doe", 20, {{"Lab", "Foo"}, {"Pug", "Bar"}}
    };
    FILE *fp = fopen("data_from_c.txt", "w");
    fwrite(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My main goal here is to write the data to the file as contiguous bytes:

```
$ xxd data_from_c.txt
00000000: 4a6f 686e 2044 6f65 0000 0000 0000 0000  John Doe........
00000010: 1400 0000 4c61 6200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Lab.........
00000020: 0000 0000 466f 6f00 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Foo.........
00000030: 0000 0000 5075 6700 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Pug.........
00000040: 0000 0000 4261 7200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Bar.........
00000050: 0000 0000                                ....
```

So far, I have tried using `namedtuple`s and the `struct` module for packing the Python values:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import struct

dog = namedtuple('dog', 'breed name')
person = namedtuple('person', 'name age pets')
p = person(
    name=b'John Doe',
    age=22,
    pets=(dog(breed=b'Lab', name=b'Foo'), dog(breed=b'Pug', name=b'Bar'))
)

with open('data_from_python.txt', 'wb') as f:
    b = struct.pack('<16s i 16s 16s 16s 16s', *p)
    f.write(b)
```

However, the `*p` unpacking does not unpack the iterable recursively. Is there a way for doing this properly?

If there is an alternative to doing this that doesn't involve using `struct` or `namedtuple`, that would be welcome too.

Comment: If its only one level of nesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: In c, arrays are contiguous, structs are not necessarily. It isn't good practice to save a struct as a binary object because the packing might be done differently on a later compilation. You should copy each field in the struct to an array and then write the array, and preferably choose an output standard for the endianness of your numerical fields.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Hi. thanks for the comment, but I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115111/13709317) and it said that the order of fields within a C struct **are in the order of declaration**, if I'm not misunderstanding it? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @FirstUser The *order* is fixed, yes, but the amount of [padding between elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306269/1968) is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to make `Person` and `Dog` dataclasses and add methods to those dataclasses that take care of packing and unpacking the data to bytes.

As an example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pathlib import Path
import struct


@dataclass
class Dog:
    breed: str = ''
    name: str = ''
    _fmt: str = field(init=False, repr=False, default='<16s16s')

    def to_bytes(self):
        return struct.pack(self._fmt, self.breed.encode(), self.name.encode())

    def from_bytes(self, bin_data):
        breed, name = struct.unpack(self._fmt, bin_data)
        self.breed = breed.rstrip(b'\x00').decode()
        self.name = name.rstrip(b'\x00').decode()
        return self


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = ''
    age: int = 0
    pets: list[Dog] = field(default_factory=list)
    _fmt: str = field(init=False, repr=False, default='<16si')

    def to_bytes(self):
        person_bytes = bytearray()
        person_bytes.extend(struct.pack(self._fmt, self.name.encode(), self.age))
        for pet in self.pets:
            person_bytes.extend(pet.to_bytes())
        return bytes(person_bytes)

    @staticmethod
    def _split_pets(seq, size):
        return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

    def from_bytes(self, bin_data: bytes):
        header_size = struct.calcsize(self._fmt)
        dog_size = struct.calcsize(Dog._fmt)
        name, self.age = struct.unpack(self._fmt, bin_data[:header_size])
        self.name = name.rstrip(b'\x00').decode()
        pets_bytes = bin_data[header_size:]

        for pet_data in self._split_pets(pets_bytes, dog_size):
            self.pets.append(Dog().from_bytes(pet_data))
        return self


def main():
    file_loc = Path('/tmp/data_from_python.txt')

    person = Person(
        name='John Doe',
        age=20,
        pets=[
            Dog(breed='Lab', name='Foo'),
            Dog('Pug', 'Bar')
        ])
    file_loc.write_bytes(person.to_bytes())

    # Test recreation of person from file
    new_person = Person().from_bytes(file_loc.read_bytes())
    print("Person from file\n", new_person)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gave the transcript:

```
Person from file
 Person(name='John Doe', age=20, pets=[Dog(breed='Lab', name='Foo'), Dog(breed='Pug', name='Bar')])
```

And the file on disk looked to match that in the question:

```
$ xxd /tmp/data_from_python.txt 
00000000: 4a6f 686e 2044 6f65 0000 0000 0000 0000  John Doe........
00000010: 1400 0000 4c61 6200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Lab.........
00000020: 0000 0000 466f 6f00 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Foo.........
00000030: 0000 0000 5075 6700 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Pug.........
00000040: 0000 0000 4261 7200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....Bar.........
00000050: 0000 0000                                ....
```

Comment: I haven't used decorators a lot and am unfamiliar with 'dataclass'. However i get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pystructs.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Person:
  File "pystructs.py", line 26, in Person
    pets: list[Dog] = field(default_factory=list)
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
` any fix for this?

Comment: Ah! I think you might be on an older version of Python. Pre 3.9?  That will require you to add the following import `from typing import List` at the top. And in `Person` replace the line `pets: list[Dog] = field(default_factory=list)` with `pets: List[Dog] = field(default_factory=list)`. There is lots of information about `dataclasses`. This for example: https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/
`

Comment: i’ve found there are packages that do this, like bstruct, dataclass_struct, dataclasses_struct. curious if people know of more.