# Parameter pack aware std::is_base_of()

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, type-traits

Is there a possibility to have a static assertion whether a type provided as template argument implements all of the types listed in the parameter pack ie. a parameter pack aware std::is_base_of()?

```
template <typename Type, typename... Requirements>
class CommonBase
{
    static_assert(is_base_of<Requirements..., Type>::value, "Invalid.");
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            parameter pack aware version of std::is_base_of()
public:
    template <typename T> T* as()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Requirements..., T>::value, "Invalid.");
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: I doubt if it's possible. Also your first `is_base_of<Requirements...>::value` doesn't have the mention of the 2nd argument.

Comment: `static_assertion` is compile time process ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647895/what-does-static-assert-do-and-what-would-you-use-it-for)),Do compiler check `is_base_of` value at compile time?

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh of course it does, as `is_base_of` is a template itself, and templates are instantiated at compile time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update for C++17:**
With C++17's fold expressions this becomes almost trivial:

```
template <typename Type, typename... Requirements>
class CommonBase
{
    static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<Type, Requirements> && ...), "Invalid.");
};
```

**Original Answer (C++11/14):**
You might use pack expansion and some static version of `std::all_of`:

```
template <bool... b> struct static_all_of;

//implementation: recurse, if the first argument is true
template <bool... tail> 
struct static_all_of<true, tail...> : static_all_of<tail...> {};

//end recursion if first argument is false - 
template <bool... tail> 
struct static_all_of<false, tail...> : std::false_type {};

// - or if no more arguments
template <> struct static_all_of<> : std::true_type {};

template <typename Type, typename... Requirements>
class CommonBase
{
    static_assert(static_all_of<std::is_base_of<Type, Requirements>::value...>::value, "Invalid.");
    //                                               pack expansion:      ^^^
};

struct Base {};
struct Derived1 : Base {};
struct Derived2 : Base {};
struct NotDerived {};

int main()
{
  CommonBase <Base, Derived1, Derived2> ok;
  CommonBase <Base, Derived1, NotDerived, Derived2> error;
}
```

The pack expansion will expand to the list of values you get by inserting every type in `Requirements...` for the question mark in `std::is_base_of<Type, ?>::value`, i.e. for the first line in main it will expand to `static_all_of<true, true>`, for the second line it will be `static_all_of<true, false, true>`

Comment: I think parenthesis are required `static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<Type, Requirements> && ...), "Invalid.");`

Comment: I mean in the "Updae for C++17" code, not in the original answer

Comment: @Tarquiscani my bad, fixed it now. (And learned that MSVC doesn't compile it regardless)

Comment: I've run into the same bug. Fortunately it's going to be fixed in MSVC 16.0

Comment: In C++17 it may be better to use `conjunction` instead of fold expressions to avoid unnecessary instantiation.

Comment: According to the classification present in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), which category would this fold expression fall under (unary left, unary right, ...)?

Answer (score 4):

Just for future reference, because I just had this problem, with C++17 you can now use fold expressions like this:

```
template<typename Base, typename... Args>
constexpr auto all_base_of()
{
    return (std::is_base_of<Base, Args>::value && ...);
}

static_assert(all_base_of<Base, A, B, C>());
```