# Force compilation error on missing static member variable in derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, type-traits

Assuming the following class hierarchy:

```
//file base.h
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase() = default;

    //a static member identifying IBase (e.g. "iid.base")
    static const char* const IID;  //initialize in implementation file
//[...]
};//class IBase

class IDerived : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IDerived() = default;

    //a static member identifying IDerived (e.g. "iid.derived")
    static const char* const IID;  //initialize in implementation file
//[...]
};//class IDerived

class IEvenMoreDerived : public IDerived
{
public:
    virtual ~IEvenMoreDerived() = default;

    //missing static const member IID!
//[...]
};//class IEvenMoreDerived
```

Every class in this hierarchy must have its own `static const tChar* const iid` which can be used to identify the object without instantiating it. In `IEvenMoreDerived` this information is missing.

Now, somewhere in the code, I have a function template where the IID is accessed:

```
//file main.cpp
#include "base.h"

template<typename T>
void queryIID()
{
    std::cout << T::IID << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    queryIID<IBase>();             //prints "iid.base"
    queryIID<IDerived>();          //prints "iid.derived"
    queryIID<IEvenMoreDerived>();  //probably prints "iid.derived"
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to get a compile time error when using `queryIID<IEvenMoreDerived>();` as `IEvenMoreDerived` doesn't have a static member `iid`. I assume it might be possible using some template magic inside function template `queryIID()`, but everything I tried didn't solve the issue.

Some additional points:

- Using `constexpr char*` instead of `static const char* const` unfortunately seems not possible as according to [The MS VS2015 Feature Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) even in VS2015 it won't be supported.
- After some digging I came across the [C++ Templates FAQ](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#base-lookup). According to this, member hiding is a "feature" of class templates. I just couldn't figure out how I might use this to solve my problem. Furthermore I don't want the class hierarchy as presented above to be changed to class.
- Among other questions, I found [this somewhat similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367221/ensure-derived-class-implements-static-method?rq=1), but it didn't entirely match my problem.

Comment: Looks like a solution looking for a problem to me. If your IIDs are needed and you don't define them, the compiler and/or linker will miss them sooner or later. At best you will replace a genuine compiler/linker error with an über cryptic bunch of template errors.

Comment: Can `typeid` help here?

Comment: You can't identify an OBJECT w/o instantiating it, by definition an object is the instantiation of a CLASS.

Comment: @kuroineko: Curently, with the  OP's code, `queryIID<IEvenMoreDerived>();` prints  `"iid.derived"`, so no linker/compiler error, just an unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, sorry. I responded too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you may delegate `Id` in an external structure, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct IdName
{
    static const char* const IID;
};

// instead of `const char* const IBase::IID = "IBase";`
// you have to use the following
template <> const char* const IdName<IBase>::IID = "IBase";
// Same for IDerived
template <> const char* const IdName<IDerived>::IID = "IDerived";
```

And you got linking error when trying to use `IdName<IEvenMoreDerived>::IID`.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/R19P5t)