# CRTP - "abstract" method in static interface

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

I am trying to work out some way to enforce contract between base CRTP class and the derived one. When using dynamic polymprhpism, one can simply do:

```
struct foo{
    virtual bar() = 0;
};
```

And the compiler will make sure that the method `bar` is implemented in deriving class, otherwise it will give (more or less) meaningful error message. Now the best I could get with CRTP to is something like this:

```
template<class Derived>
struct base {
    void stuff(){
        static_cast<Derived &>(*this).baz();  
    }
};
```

Which will somehow enforce implementation of `baz` in derived class but is not really readable and clear what the contract between base and derived class is. So my question is, is there a way to do this better? I am aware of C++20 Concepts and that they would be perfect solution for this case, but I am looking for C++11/C++14 solution to make it as clean as possible.

Comment: You can check the implementations exist at compile time by using function pointer instantiations with derived.

Comment: Related if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367221/ensure-derived-class-implements-static-method

Comment: More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354501/ensure-that-class-derived-from-parent-crtp-class-implements-function

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could You give example in an answer? I don't get what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the derived class is always incomplete when a base is defined one solution I use is to delay "concept check" instantiation using a defaulted template parameter:

```
template<class T>
using has_baz = decltype(std::declval<T&>().baz());

template<class Derived>
struct base{
  template<class T = Derived, has_baz<T>* =nullptr>
  void stuff(){/*...*/}
  };
```

Notice, c++20 concepts will not solve this special issue and the delaying of the concept check will still be necessary. The advantage is that the compilation error will be clearer.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPshV0)