# Ensure derived class implements static method while maintaining default move / move assign

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, crtp, static-assert

I'd like to ensure some derived classes implement a static method and found this SO question: [Ensure derived class implements static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367221/ensure-derived-class-implements-static-method) The top answer uses CRTP to solve the issue with a `static_assert` in the base class destructor to ensure that the template argument type implements a `static int foo(int)`.

However, as noted by a comment on the answer "There is a slight issue with this answer: writing out a destructor has the consequence of disabling the generation of a move constructor and move assignment operator. It also prevents the object from being trivially_destructible. So, while it works, there are downsides to the approach (and such downsides apply to other special members)." – @Matthieu M

Is there a way to avoid this downside? I've tried moving the `static_assert` to both a member function and static member function of `Base`, but in both cases it doesn't produce a compile-time error when a derived class doesn't implement `static int foo()`. Here's the code I've been working with (tweaked from the above SO thread):

```
#include <type_traits>


template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    //~Base() //This works as expected! Compile error because Bad doesn't implement static int foo()
    //{
    //    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(T::foo()), int>::value, "ERROR: No 'static int foo()' member provided");
    //}

    static void static_test() //This does not work. No compile time error.
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(T::foo()), int>::value, "ERROR: No 'static int foo()' member provided");
    }
};

class Good : public Base<Good> {
public:
    static int foo() { return 42; };
};

class Bad : public Base<Bad> {
public:
    static double foo() { return 42; };
};

int main()
{
    Good g;
    Bad b;
}
```

Comment: You can add to the base class: `class_name(c'tor param) = default;` to get the default back for selected constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a concept that the class needs to fulfil. You can simply check for it after the definition of the class, probably easiest with a `static_assert`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
static constexpr bool assert_is_fooable() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(T::foo()), int>::value, "ERROR: No 'static int foo()' member provided");
    static_assert(condition_2(), "ERROR: condition 2");
    // More specific error messages given above, this is always
    // true so it can be used in a static_assert
    return true;
}

class Good {
public:
    static int foo() { return 42; };
};

static_assert(assert_is_fooable<Good>());
```

And it even works if that class is unused anywhere else. You could also put the assert at the place where `Good` is used that expects it to have `static int foo()` instead.

This allows the class to be trivially destructible and does not suppress the move constructor or move assignment operator, since it does not actually modify the class.

Comment: Actually, this will probably work better for my use-case than using CRTP. Simpler to wrap my head around too. Great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I think you are thinking too complicated. The workaround to let the compiler generate definition for special members you want to be generated is to declare them `default`:

```
struct foo {
    ~foo() {} // prevents the compiler to generate move constructor
    foo(foo&&) = default; // compiler generates a move constructor
};
```

Comment: That's much simpler than imagined! I'm quite new to move semantics but I'm using a library that provides data structures which require move construction / assignment. Does this also restore the default move assignment operator, and if not is there a similar way to do this too?

Comment: @Verwirrt no, I only used the move constructor as an example. In general, if presence of a user defined special member prevents the compiler to generate another spcial member you just need to declare it as `default` to let the compiler generate it.