# What is the purpose of a 'switch 0' statement in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I [came across](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/mkfs.c) the following line of code, and I can't figure out what it does.

```
#define static_assert(a, b) do { switch (0) case 0: case (a): ; } while (0)
```

What does the `switch (0)` part do? Assuming `0` is equivalent to `false`, does that mean we never enter the switch statement?

Also for the line `case (a)`, how can you give the unknown `a` variable as a case?

Comment: All this seems to be doing is checking that `a` is a compile-time constant.  `b` isn't even used.  The code it expands to just falls through without really doing anything.  `switch (0)` is no different from `switch (100)` or any other value.  It branches to `case 0` and execution continues from there.  And `a` shouldn't be a variable, it's whatever you pass to the macro.  It should be a constant.  It you pass a variable, you will get a compile-time error.

Comment: [`static_assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647895/995714) can give you some hint although the intention and usage here is different and that name is not a good choice

Comment: Defective as an implementation of the standard `static_assert` as it won't work outside of a function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`switch(0)` will always execute the block of code associated with the `case 0:` block; still, here there's no actually executed code - both cases are empty.

The point here is to make the compiler angry *at compile time* if the asserted expression (`a`) is not verified: in this case, the expanded macro will have two `case 0:` - the one provided explicitly, and the one that uses the result of the asserted expression (so, 0 in case it failed); this results in a `switch` with two identical `case`, which is not allowed and makes the compiler stop with an error at compile time.

This will also fail if the passed expression is not a constant evaluated at compile time (as you cannot have runtime-determined `case` values), which is also expected from a `static_assert`.